# How to intercept/sniff all tcp/udp network traffic for specific application?

Tags: c#, .net, sniffing

Basically, I want to know how can I intercept/sniff all tcp/udp network traffic for some specific application like the tunneling applications do? For example ProxyCap allows to tunnel all traffic for specific application to some proxy. So as I can understand those programs can intercept all traffic before they change/reroute it.

I've tried using winpcap but even Wireshark. But it doesn't work if you have proxycap installed. I mean, it does not capture application traffic:

1. Traffic from my program intercepted by the ProxyCap
2. ProxyCap redirects it all to localhost proxy
3. My localhost proxy is actually a Your-Freedom gateway proxy
4. Your-freedom proxy sends traffic to their servers (traffic goes to internet).

When I start Wireshark sniffing (which is based on winpcap driver) I see only traffic from step #4 (when it goes to the internet). And this traffic is not raw (it's packed/encoded) so it doesn't work for me to sniff it.

So since I need to sniff all the traffic I thought that I either find a way to sniff before ProxyCap (or after it, but I don't think it's possible since traffic redirected to the loopback proxy).

I want to ask you guys - is there a way to intercept/sniff traffic like ProxyCap (or other tunneling applications) do?

Comment: Unless you're asking how to do this in a specific language/with a specific library, I'm thinking this belongs on superuser

Comment: Well, it would be great to have this working in C#.
But if anyone here can share the solution in C++ or Java - I'll understand it too.

Comment: Some time ago I developed a sniffer using Komodia library version 4 (http://www.komodia.com/index.php?page=newtcpip4.html). You can try if they work in your environment.

Comment: I guess there would be an answer of OP narrowed the question to one programming language.

Comment: Done. Though it's not very actual for me anymore, I hope this would help someone else is answered.